# you are trying to add a non-nullable field 'description' to wine without a default

Tags: python, django

I tried to add a description column and i tried to make changes in models.py. However, when I was trying to migrate I get this error

```
C:\Users\Adhista Chapagain\Desktop\winerama>python manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'description' to wine without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option:
```

models.py code looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
import numpy as np

class Wine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    images = models.ImageField(null = True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and code for load_wine

```
def save_wine_from_row(wine_row):
    wine = Wine()
    wine.id = wine_row[0]
    wine.name = wine_row[1]
    wine.images = wine_row[2]
    wine.description = wine_row[3]
    wine.save()
```

Comment: Edit your description column: description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you are trying to add a column to an existing table which does not have a default value, but it is not allowed to be blank. So this is an impossible situation - either it should have a default value, or make it "null" in the database. Unless you provide a solution, the migration cannot continue.

So you have few options:

1. Give a default value, which will be applied to all existing records.
2. Make the field optional (ie, set `null=True`).
3. Give it a default value in models (`default="No Description"`)

Just pick an option and then migrate will work.

Answer (score 0):

When you add fields to an already-existing model, if those fields are not 'nullable' (i.e. You don't have `null=True` on the field) then you need to provide the migration with a default to use for all existing rows in the database for that model. It doesn't know at this point whether there are any or not, so you have to do this even if the database is empty.

Just choose one of the options and provide a default (even if that is just an empty string).